# How to extract text from pdf with complex layouts using python?

Tags: python, pdf, extract, text-extraction, pdftotext

I am extracting text from pdf but it's hard to extract for the complex layouts like a 2-column pdf and different scenarios of pdf's in a table like table with borders or no borders, and combined scenarios like table in a two column or adjacent table . it is getting hard when all layouts are in one pdf. Is there a way to overcome this issue of extracting text from pdf without loosing its structure.

I tried by getting it's layout dictionary of a pdf using PyMuPDF with it's co-ordinates or bbox but i couldn't differenciate between different layouts of pdf.

Comment: There is no silver bullet as you seem to hope. You have to fight your own way through the jungle of what in PDF (almost) always is simple unstructured text. You can use `page.find_tables()` in PyMuPDF for tables and `page.get_text("dict")` to extract text with all meta information, but otherwise ... **Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: I am trying to extract row-wise approach for tables and column wise for a column layout. if there are both in one page of a pdf , i want to extract in the order of the page only.

If there is a table in a page then i want to extarct as a text only but row wise even if some records have multiple lines also.